# reuse storyboard and uicontrollers

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I have designed in a storyboard a login/password Controller. The textfields are linked to the controller with the famous ctrl+drag.

Is there a way to reuse storyboard + controller somewhere else in the App. For instance I want to give the user the ability to change his login from a setting menu and I do not want to have to create a new class and to clone its storyboard representation.

What is the best practice in this case to reuse what I have already done?

Comment: You could reuse it using         `self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "StoryboardIdentifier") as! ClassType`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what view controller's identifiers are used for. 
In your storyboard, set an identifier for LoginViewController, after that, you'll only need to present your `LoginViewController` or push it to your navigation stack. Your code should look something like this:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "yourStoryboardName", bundle: nil)
let loginViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "loginViewController") as! LoginViewController

// If you are in a navigation controller:
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(loginViewController, animated: true)

// If you just want to present a new view:
self.present(loginViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

This way, you'll push/present a new view controller that has the layout specified in storyboard for the identifier "loginViewController".
All text fields and buttons in that view controller should be handled in the class specified for the view controller which, in your case, should be `LoginViewController`.

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse you can. I'm using this code.
Try:

**OBJECTIVE-C:**

```
UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyBoardName bundle:nil];
UIViewController *upcomingViewController = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: storyBoardID];
UINavigationController *controller = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:upcomingViewController];
```